# Failed to import 'tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt' in tensorflow r1.14

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

I have installed the `Tensorflow r1.14` and want to use `TF-TRT`. However, the following error occurs:

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt'"

when running the sample code. The same error occurs with `Tensorflow r1.13`. So my question is do I need to install the `tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt` library separately? If yes, how?

Additionally, I can run the sample code of the `TensorRT`, e.g. `sampleINT8`, successfully. Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKVER.jpg) to see my successful sample code run.

This leads me to believe that `TensorRT` is installed properly. However, the `TF-TRT` still doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

> In TF 1.14, TF-TRT was moved to the core from contrib.
>
> You need to import it like this: from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import > trt_convert as trt
>
> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt/blob/master/tftrt/examples/image-classification/image_classification.py#L22

This is the correct answer for Linux.

However, if you're using Windows: the TensorRT Python API (and therefore TF-TRT) is not supported for Windows at the moment, so the TensorFlow python packages aren't built with TensorRT.

Answer (score 2):

In TF 1.14, TF-TRT was moved to the core from contrib.

You need to import it like this: 
`from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt`

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt/blob/master/tftrt/examples/image-classification/image_classification.py#L22

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to `import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt` you need to have `tensorflow-gpu` *version >= 1.7 installed on your system*. Maybe you could try installing the `tensorflow-gpu` library with a:

`pip install tensorflow-gpu`

Check out the Windows section of the [GPU documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) as well. Also, I would try updating your `tensorflow` version with a:

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

to ensure you're up to date there as well. Check out this section of the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for additional support.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: The tf.__version__ is 1.13.1 which is >=1.7. I have also check the folder 'tensorflow\contrib' and there is no subfolder called tensorrt. I don't think the pip installation come up with tensorrt. What else can I do now?

Comment: Maybe you could try downloading the tensorrt driver directly  from nvidia: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-install-guide/index.html#downloading

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities

1. Have you installed tensorflow-gpu instead of tensorflow?
2. From your screenshot it looks like you're using Windows. I had the same problem. There seems no `tensorrt` module under `contrib` in TF windows distribution however linux has it (I tried 1.13.1).