# Tensorflow > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Have spent a couple days troubleshooting. This is the complete installation guide for a course I am taking

https://github.com/reigngt09/Pose-Estimation/tree/master/1.%20Pose%20Estimation%20Installation%20Guide

When I try and enter the following in cmd

```
$python run_webcam.py --camera video.mp4
```

I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

The offending line is

```
import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt
```

Here are my setup specs

> Windows 10
>
> Python 3.6.8
>
> CUDA 10.0
>
> cuDNN v 7.6.2
>
> Tensorflow (gpu) 1.14.0
>
> GeForce GTX 960M
>
> Driver version 431.60
>
> Intel Core i7-6700HQ 2.6 GHz*

Any feedback or troubleshooting steps appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import the following way:

```
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
```

https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html#usage-example

Comment: Thanks. Actually tried that already but was then getting another error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt"

Comment: Is it possible tensorflow is in correctly installed? When I do a $pip list I get tensorflow 1.14.0, tensorflow-estimator 1.14.0, tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0b1

Comment: get almost identical error if instead of cmd I run  using Anaconda prompt with Python 3.7.3 "No module named 'tensorflow.python.compiler."

Comment: confirmed that import tensorflow DOES work in a Python shell.

Comment: so bottom line is that the tensorRT module is missing. Then how to install? A quick google shows no Windows installer or support?
I already tried uninstalling then reinstalling tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Does 'tf.__version__' output 1.14.0? tensorflow(for CPU) and tensorflow-gpu(for GPU) are mutually exclusive. Can you uninstall tensorflow/tensorflow-gpu and install only tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0?

Comment: same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55523680/failed-to-import-tensorflow-contrib-tensorrt-in-tensorflow-r1-14

Comment: yes, tried uninstalled just tensorflow and ran again. Same error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt

Comment: Please uninstall tensorflow-gpu as well and then install only tensorflow-gpu and try again.

Comment: thanks. Progress? Now getting different error    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named tensorflow.python

offending line from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensoflow

Comment: finally have working...a few more missing modules, matplotlib, pycocotools...now the issue is performace!